# How to implement reconciliation system in apache flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on building a reconciliation system by consuming data from two different kafka streams and reconciling the data content by joining on one common shared Id.

Initially I had used interval join for this, but got stuck in an issue that it only supports inner join. So if I don't get data from one stream for common shared Id, that particular data is missed.

Is there any possible way to get all the data of both streams and then do interval join for matching records and flush unmatched into some elasticsearch/hive DB?

Answer (score 0):

Interval join with this functionality is not impossible to make but it's difficult to develop, I think.

If you don't have a strict requirement for implementing an interval join. You can use Co-Group with a Tumbling Window or Sliding Window etc to implement an outer join. You can separate the successful and failed matches afterward with a filter. Then, you can perform join logic for successful ones and push the failed ones to some sink.

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>>> stream = source1.coGroup(source2)
            .where((x) -> x.f0)
            .equalTo((x) -> x.f0)
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(3)))
            .apply(new CoGroupFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>,
                Tuple2<List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>>>() {
                @Override
                public void coGroup(Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> first, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> second, Collector<Tuple2<List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>>> out) throws Exception {
                    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    first.forEach(lst::add);
                    second.forEach(lst2::add);
                    out.collect(new Tuple2<>(lst, lst2));
                }
            });
        // If any of the list is empty. Key didn't match
        DataStream<Tuple2<List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>>> misMatch = 
            stream.filter(x -> x.f0.isEmpty() || x.f1.isEmpty());
        misMatch.addSink(new SomeSink());


        DataStream<Tuple2<List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, List<Tuple2<String, Integer>>>> match = 
            stream.filter(x -> !x.f0.isEmpty() && !x.f1.isEmpty());
        DataStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> joined = match.flatMap((x, y) -> {
            // your join logic.
            y.collect(new Tuple3<>("your", "joined tuple", 1);
        });

        joined.addSink(new SomeOtherSink());
```